# HTTP won't redirect to HTTPS

Tags: http, https, cloudflare

I have a PHP webapp on Heroku that uses Cloudflare page rules to redirect all http requests to https. This works perfectly in almost all instances except for when I append a referral tracking identifier to the end of the url.

Cloudflare page rules are:

```
http://mywebsite.com -> Always use HTTPS - ON

https://cdn.mywebsite.com/* -> Cache Level: Cache Everything - ON

http://mywebsite.com/subscribe -> Always use HTTPS - OFF
```

typing `http://mywebsite.com` redirects the user to `https://mywebsite.com`

typing `http://mywebsite.com?yp_ref=user60` does not redirect the user to https

How can I ensure that all requests are redirected to https?

Comment: You need to show us your Cloudflare rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to force all traffic for your zone to https is to do so on the Crypto tab with the aptly labeled feature "Always use HTTPS". But it looks like some portions of your site don't support SSL (which is sub-optimal). Then you could use a page rule for Flexible SSL for your subscribe link.

With the current setup you need at least 2 things..

Add * to the ned of your first page rule.

Your page rules look like they might be out of order when you do that as the /subscribe (3rd rule) will not fire since it is covered by the first so you would need to move it to the top in terms of priority. (Still flexible SSL or better yet fixing it for full SSL would be better here).